# Checking if values from two arrays are equal. They are but VBA thinks they're not (UPDATE: Resolution at bottom)

Tags: vba, excel

I've run into a strange problem:
I have two separate arrays with 3 attributes I'm trying to match to determine if all three attributes match, partial matches, or no matches.

I have a loop to loop through the values in the first array and a second nested loop within that loop to loop through the second array for each line of the first array.

Here's where it get's weird: I have three If-statement gates that check if the first attribute (amount) is equal in each of the arrays, then the second attribute (trace), and finally the last attribute (customer).
I have a line item in one array that matches on the amount (as it should), but then fails on the trace check (where it shouldn't).

I've used Debug.Print to see if the values are the same. They are. I checked that the format from the original data is the same (i.e. no spaces/hidden characters etc.). I made sure that when the array is populated from the cells, it uses the .Value method.

Even though I've checked all these, and the Debug.Print shows they are the same, it fails the check when comparing the two values.

Here's the code:

```
For RemMatchLoop = LBound(RemAmtMatchArray, 2) To UBound(RemAmtMatchArray, 2) Step 1
    PerfectMatchFound = False
    For MMMatchLoop = LBound(MMAmtMatchArray, 2) To UBound(MMAmtMatchArray, 2) Step 1
        If MMAmtMatchArray(MMAmountCol, MMMatchLoop) = RemAmtMatchArray(RemAmountCol, RemMatchLoop) Then
            Debug.Print "MM Trace: " & MMAmtMatchArray(MMTraceCol, MMMatchLoop)
            Debug.Print "Rem Trace: " & RemAmtMatchArray(RemTraceCol, RemMatchLoop)
            If MMAmtMatchArray(MMTraceCol, MMMatchLoop) = RemAmtMatchArray(RemTraceCol, RemMatchLoop) Then
                If MMAmtMatchArray(MMCustomerCol, MMMatchLoop) = RemAmtMatchArray(RemCustomerCol, RemMatchLoop) Then
                    ReDim Preserve RemPerfectMatchArray(1 To RemLastCol, 1 To RemPerfectMatchCount) As Variant
                    For RemPerfectMatchColFill = 1 To RemInBalanceCol Step 1
                        RemPerfectMatchArray(RemPerfectMatchColFill, RemPerfectMatchCount) = RemAmtMatchArray(RemPerfectMatchColFill, RemMatchLoop)
                        If RemPerfectMatchColFill = RemAmountCol Then
                            Debug.Print "Perfect Match Amount: " & RemPerfectMatchArray(RemPerfectMatchColFill, RemPerfectMatchCount)
                        End If
                    Next RemPerfectMatchColFill
                    RemPerfectMatchCount = RemPerfectMatchCount + 1
                    PerfectMatchFound = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next MMMatchLoop
```

Here's what the Debug.Print has spit out regarding the line item in question:

```
MM Trace: 1234
Rem Trace: 1234
```

So, both traces are the same, but when it passes the line:

```
If MMAmtMatchArray(MMTraceCol, MMMatchLoop) = RemAmtMatchArray(RemTraceCol, RemMatchLoop) Then
```

It detects them as not-equal.

UPDATE: One type is Double and the other is String. Not sure why, because the data the array resulting in a String value pulls from is not Text format and is a number.

Additionally, when the data is populated into the array, it uses the .Value method, as seen below:

```
For RemAmtMatchColFill = 1 To RemLastCol Step 1
            RemAmtMatchArray(RemAmtMatchColFill, RemAmtMatchCount) = RemWS.Cells(RemAmtMatchLoop, RemAmtMatchColFill).Value
        Next RemAmtMatchColFill
```

Not sure why then it's detecting a string...

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm completely baffled.

***RESOLUTION***
After using Typename() suggested in the comments to identify what types are being compared, it was determined that the Variant array was converting Currency data types in both source data into Double type in one array and String type in another. While it's strange that it's doing this, by using CStr() to convert both values to strings while comparing fixed the issue.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: Huh... that's... that's a neat trick. I didn't know about that. So, it's stating that one is a Double and the other is a String. Do I just need to use a CLng to fix that?

Comment: You need to find out where string type comes from while numeric type expected.

Comment: And could you please simplify the variable names in the code? [Just a, b, i, j ..](https://pastebin.com/uwjYC340) instead of that awkward.

Comment: I'd simplify it, but I'm passing this code off later, and I need the variables to be descriptive enough to follow along for people less adept.

Comment: Check `Debug.Print TypeName(RemWS.Cells(RemAmtMatchLoop, RemAmtMatchColFill).Value)`, if it's a numeric then implicit type conversion might be the reason.

Comment: I checked the type on the data for both arrays, just to be sure. The input data type for both is "Currency". Sorry, but I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: I suppose you may try to convert each value from sheet with `CDbl()` before putting it into array.

Comment: your code would be more readable if you get rid of all the leading capitals. reserved words tend to be capitalized .... use `mmCustomerCol` instead of `MMCustomerCol`  ..... `mmAmtMatchArray` instead of `MMAmtMatchArray` ... maybe even drop the _Array_ from the name, since it is clear that it is an array

Comment: drop the text _Match_ from all the variable names (i think it is in almost all of them) ... what is the point of having the same text in all your variable names, it does not differentiate them.

Comment: do **not** use **nested** `If` statements. .... set a counter to zero .... each if statement increments the counter when match is found  .... at end if _counter = 3_ then --- perfect match  ...... and so on

Comment: Why don't you join the arrays and check them against each other? Iterating through the values of the array is extremely slow `If join(MMAmtMatchArray,"|") = join(RemAmtMatchArray,"|") then msgbox "They match" 'We know it's a match if this is true` You can off course do this to the debug window with `debug.print join(MMAmtMatchArray,"|")` and `debug.print join(RemAmtMatchArray,"|")` This will match because they will both be strings

Comment: @DanDonoghue Joining them is a good idea to make sure they're both the same Type. I don't think I can just check if the whole arrays are equal to each other. There are three common columns between the two that may or may not be equal. I need to check that in a given dimension, three values in a second dimension are equal in both arrays. Is there a faster way to do this other than iterating through all values of the array?

Comment: My apologies, I thought you wanted to compare the whole array. Convert your elements when comparing, CSTR() will convert to a string, CDBL to a double etc, that way you know you are comparing like types

Comment: @DanDonoghue Thanks Dan. I wasn't sure if I could convert the elements at that stage, but it worked. Thank you!